# Getting unexpected colour output when converting from numpy array to image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library, numpy-ndarray

I'm in the process of trying to learn and understand the relationship of images to numpy arrays, by experimenting with converting arrays to images and vice versa, just to get a better visual understanding of how images actually look like as arrays, with the effect of different pixel values have inside different positions in the array and its axis. I wanted to start from a very simple numpy array and see how the position of different values, in a numpy array, look like as an image. So I created a simple numpy array (below). Simple at least to the context of a typical image. Basically I created an array shape of `36, 33, 3`, (simulating height, width and 3 channels for RGB). Note below the array, the line - `array = array.transpose(1,2,0)`, so that I can have the correct order of `36, 33, 3`. I started out with channel 1 being all 1s. Channel 2 all 2s and channel 3 all 3s. No particular reason, just wanted to experiment:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]],
                 [[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]],
                 [[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]]])

array = array.transpose(1,2,0)
```

When I change all values to 255, I'm expecting the image to look completely white:

```
array[:, :, 0] += 254
array[:, :, 1] += 253
array[:, :, 2] += 252
```

However, when I convert the array to image I get the the following image (below), which looks like a black background with horizontal white lines running across the image. At least it looks like white. If you zoom in, it's a weird white with red dots at the top, green dots in the middel and blue dots at the bottom of the horizontal lines. So I wanted to understand why I get such image instead of complete white colour?

Original image:
[image]

80% zoomed in:
[image]

Finally, can someone recommend of a good learning resource about converting arrays to images and vice versa, where I could get a better understanding of how pixel value and positioning is actually visualised in an image and vice versa (how to access the pixel values inside an array of an image).

Many thanks in advance.

Update:

Here's the code I used for converting the array to an image (as requested by  `Cris Luengo` in the comment section):

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.fromarray(array, 'RGB')
img.save('my.png')
img.show()
```

Comment: There's overflow most probably.

Comment: I read the code :) Hence, the quote - `most probably.`.

Comment: Thanks Divakar. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "overflow", in the context of this question? Thanks

Comment: Just added an update in my post, sharing the code for converting the array to an image, as requested.

Comment: Here's one - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: You're better off using matplotlib. There's an [`imsave`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imsave.html) that works just fine with NumPy arrays.

Comment: Thank you Divakar and Cris Luengo for your contribution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Image.fromarray` [uses `arr.tobytes()`](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/Image.py#L2659) to obtain the underlying data in `arr`.
Since the underlying data should be unsigned 1-byte ints, `arr` needs to have dtype `uint8`:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

arr = np.tile([[[1]],[[2]],[[3]]], (1,36,33))

arr = arr.transpose(1,2,0)
arr[:, :, 0] += 254
arr[:, :, 1] += 253
arr[:, :, 2] += 252

arr = arr.astype('uint8')
img = Image.fromarray(arr, 'RGB')
img.save('/tmp/my2.png')
```

---

Notice the difference when `array` is the original array of dtype `int64` (or `int32` depending on your OS), and `arr` is of dtype `uint8`:

```
In [285]: array.tobytes()[:10]
Out[285]: b'\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00'

In [286]: arr.tobytes()[:10]
Out[286]: b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
```

---

To preserve your code with minimal changes, you could specify the dtype when creating the array (instead of calling `astype('uint8')` later):

```
array = np.array([...], dtype='uint8')
```

Then the rest of your code would work as expected.

Comment: Wow, super. That worked. Thanks `unutbu` :)  Yes I tried both your code variations of specifying  `dtype='uint8'` at the array definition or after, and both worked fine. One question I have, just before marking your answer as solution. You mentioned about the `int64` and `int32`.  My OS, is Windows 10 (64-bit), so I was excpeting int64. However, when I printed the original array I got `int32`, when using the code `array.dtype`. Why is it int32 and not int64? Also what difference would it make to the image if it's int32, int64 or uint8?

Comment: I believe it depends on how NumPy was compiled. You can check the NumPy bit architecture with [`sysinfo.platform_bits`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33553549/190597).

Comment: Since your `array` has dtype `int32` by default, `array.tobytes()[:10]` should return `b'\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00'` (assuming your OS is little-endian). Notice that `b'\xff\x00\x00\x00'` represents 4 bytes -- i.e. 32 bits, and the `int32` dtype means each value in the array is represented by 32 bits.

Comment: Oh I see, so does that mean instead of 1 byte (with maximum range of 0-255) for each pixel value, we get 4 byte, which is 2 to the power of 32 = 4,294,967,296, maximum value for each pixel? Is that correct? Converting to uint8, is this so it's easier to process by python and machine learning libraries, or is there another reason?

Comment: The maximum value representable by an array of dtype `int32` is `2**31 - 1`  which equals `2147483647` (you can check this with `np.iinfo('int32').max`). Remember, these are signed ints. The maximum value representable by `uint8` is 255. In RGB format, each *pixel* is represented by 24 bits -- 8-bits per channel. So when you pass `b'\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00'` to `fromarray`, PIL is interpreting this to mean the first pixel has color (255, 0, 0), the second pixel has (0, 255, 0), the third (0, 0, 255). That's why you see a moire pattern.

Comment: Many thanks for the great explanation, and apologies for the late reply. I was reading further about some of the concepts you mentioned in your explanation (like encoding and hex) to get a better understanding, before responding to you. So hopefully if I understood you correctly, for the last part of your explanation, the reason I got the moire pattern is because my array type was `int32`. I didn't convert to uint8, which is RGB format. Then I passed the array to `fromarray` specifying `RGB` format, yet my array is `int32`, so it interpretted 3 pixels next to each other of (255, 0, 0)

Comment: .. (0, 255, 0) and (0, 0, 255), or red, green and blue next to each other consecutively, rather than 255 for red channel, 255 for green channel and 255 for blue channel, i.e. in their separate channels (to achieve the white colour). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you zoom in on moire pattern, you'll see the pixels from left to right are red, green, blue, black, and then it repeats. That makes sense because `int32` values are 4 bytes long, while RGB pixels are 3 bytes long. The least common multiple is 12 bytes -- i.e. 4 pixels. So every 4 pixels the pattern repeats. Finally, `len(array.tobytes())` is 14256 (= 36*33*3*4) bytes. But the image is only 36*33 pixels, which can be specified with 36*33*3 = 3564 bytes. So this suggests `fromarray` used the first 3564 bytes in `array.tobytes()` and ignored the rest.

Answer (score 2):

You're not showing all of your code, so it is difficult to identify the exact error. Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

width = 36
height = 33

array = np.zeros([height, width, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
array[:, :, 0] += 255
array[:, :, 1] += 255
array[:, :, 2] += 255

plt.imshow(array)
plt.show()
```

The image shown here will be completely white. Hopefully this can help you identify your error. Good luck.

Comment: Thank for the solution. That worked :). Note, I have shared my entire code with the update to my post. Maybe it was after you posted your response though. No worries. I would mark your response as a solution if I could mark more than one response as a solution, but SO, as you know, only allows for one response marked as a solution. @unutbu also provided a solution, his also showed how to convert and save as an image file which is what I was after. But good to see how to plot the array as well, with your solution. I have upvoted your solution. many thanks again :)